# Hebrew alphabet spelling for phrase in psalm 23, and the phrase "God is my refuge"?

Tags: words, hebrew, translation, aleph-bet-letters

I find the Hebrew alphabet to be very beautiful but as of right now I only know the meaning of a couple of symbols. I would love to have the correct original spelling for the beginning of psalm 23, "The Lord is my shepherd, I shall not want", and also if possible the writing of "God is my refuge".

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2623.htm

Comment: Is this on-topic?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Perhaps Too Localized.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Maybe better for Hebrew Language SE. . .

Comment: @WAF that would be a better place but the site is still in proposal.  I see no close votes on this question currently.

Answer (score 2):

> ה׳ רֹעִי לֹא אֶחְסָר

is the quotation from Psalm 23. The other can be worded various ways. One is

> ה׳ מַחְסִי

(from Ps. 91:9).

In general, to find the original Hebrew of a verse in the Jewish Bible, try [Mechon Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0.htm); to find the Hebrew of an arbitrary English phrase likely to be in the Bible, [search the same site](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3ahttp://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/+%22is+my+refuge%22).

Comment: Perhaps you can include a link to the relevant section and some information about where find Hebrew verses in general? That will help make this entire thread more useful for the future. As it is now it's sorta too localized.

Comment: @DoubleAA, good now?

Comment: It may also help to transliterate the quotations in your answer being that the OP does not fluently read Hebrew.

Comment: @Lee, he only asked for the original spelling. I assume that if he cared about pronunciation then he'd have indicated as much.

Comment: @msh210 Fair enough. I was indeed making an assumption, but I thought it was a valid one.